# Solving $f'' +f \leq 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question : $$f'' (t) + f(t) \leq 0,\ f(0)\geq 0,\ f(b) \geq 0,\ b<\pi$$ Then show that $$ f(t)\geq 0,\ t\in [0,b] $$

In my thought any connected component in $\{x|f(x)\geq 0 \}$ is longer than that of $\{ x| f_0(x)=\sin\ x\geq 0\} $

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not a pde, unless you mistyped something?

Comment: This is not a second order elliptic eq ?

Comment: what's happening with $f(0)$?

Comment: I add more conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I initially made a mistake in the calculations, but it turns out to be solvable.

Over the interval $[0, b]$ we have that $\sin t \geq 0$ since $b \lt \pi$.

Thus multiply the inequality by $\sin t$ to get $f''(t)\sin t + f(t)\sin t \leq 0$.

Thus $f''(t)\sin t + f'(t)\cos t - f'(t)\cos t + f(t)\sin t \leq 0$.

Therefore $(f'(t)\sin t)'-(f(t)\cos t)' = (f'(t)\sin t - f(t)\cos t)' \leq 0$.

After integrating from $0$ to $t$, we get $f'(t)\sin t - f(t)\cos t \leq f'(0)\sin 0 - f(0)\cos 0 = -f(0)$.

Dividing by $\sin^2 t$ over the interval $(0, b]$ we have $\left(\frac{f(t)}{\sin t}\right)' \leq -f(0)\csc^2(t).$

Therefore after integrating from $t$ to $b$, we have

$\frac{f(t)}{\sin t} \geq \frac{f(b)}{\sin b} + f(0)(\cot t - \cot b)$ and therefore,

$ f(t) \geq \frac{f(b)}{\sin b} \sin t + f(0) (\cos t - \cos b)$ for all $ t \in [0, b]$ (the case at $0$ must be true by continuity).

Since $f(0) \geq 0$ and $f(b) \geq 0$, and $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0, \pi]$, the RHS is nonnegative and $f(t) \geq 0$ on $[0, b]$.

Comment: Actually we have $f'(0)\sin0 - f(0)\cos0=-f(0)$.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. Fortunately it didn't break the argument because I had also made the error that $\cos b - \cos t \geq 0$, which is obviously the wrong way since as I mentionned $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0, b]$. So I had two wrongs cancelling each other.

Comment: Interestingly, for the case $t = 0$ I had to use continuity instead, but if we explicitly plug $t = 0$ in the inequality we get $f(0) \geq f(0)(1 - \cos b)$. 
If $f(0) \gt 0$, then $\cos b \geq 0$, and $b \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. This gives a constraint on $b$ which was not explicit in the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative end to Tob's answer: Defining $g(t)=f'(t)\sin t - f(t)\cos t$, we have $g'(t) \le 0$ and $g(0)= -f(0) \le 0$ so that $g(t)\le0, \forall t \in [0, b]$. From $\frac{g(t)}{\sin^2 t}=(\frac{f(t)}{\sin\ t})'$ we get $f(t)=f(b)(\frac{\sin t}{\sin b})^2 - \sin^2 t \int_t^b \frac{g(s)}{\sin^2 s}ds \ge 0$ by integrating from $t$ to $b$.